# Can an OpenPGP certificate be imported into Windows Certificate Manager?

Tags: certificates, windows, digital-signature, gnupg, openpgp

I have a clearsigned .gcode document that I would like to be able to deploy through the Windows Certificate Store. Is this possible? If not, are there any good alternatives?

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't. The Windows Certificate Store has no support for OpenPGP, but relies on X.509 certificates. OpenPGP and X.509 certificates use a different format, although the underlying cryptographic principles are pretty much the same.

If you need to support the Windows Certificate Store, use X.509 certificates. Very likely your use case will require one issued by an already included certification authority.

Comment: I created X.509 certificates in OpenSSL and packaged the keys and certs in a PKCS12 file. I would try using SignTool at this point, but I know SignTool does not recognize .gcode (or .stl) files. Are there any alternatives to SignTool that WILL sign .gcode or .stl files?

Comment: It is discouraged to ask heavily altered follow-up questions in comments on Stack Exchange, asking a new question instead is preferred. Software recommendation is off topic on most sites, consider asking the question on [softwarerects.stackexchange.com](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com). I'd also recommend to include a short description of what you want to achieve (and what kind of files these are) and why you want to do it, as this might change the recommended products.